# Close PIP window by Android Accessibility service

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility, picture-in-picture

Accessibility service can detect PIP(picture-in-picture) windows, but interesting is it can close such windows?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is can be only one PIP window in the system. So the solution is - open your own PIP activity and close it right away after opening. That's all.